# What is the word for a statement which most probably is wrong but is said to convey a different meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, sentence, ambiguity

Example : Paul McCartney said "If Slaughter Houses had glass walls, everyone would be a vegetarian." Now, it also means that everyone who works at a slaughter house is a vegetarian. But, what Paul actually wanted to convey was that slaughter houses are so cruel that you'd feel like quitting non-veg completely. Is there any word for such statements?

Comment: Perhaps *hyperbole*.

Comment: Hyperbole implies exaggeration, as in *"I saw this movie a thousand times."*

Comment: @A.P. Yes, and the statement that "if slaughterhouses had glass walls the entire world would turn vegetarian" is an exaggeration.

Comment: A small point about your interpretation: I think the phrase isn't talking about the workers. They would be able to see how animals are slaughtered with or without glass walls. The point is a glass-walled slaughterhouse would let everyone who passed by see how their meat is slaughtered.

Comment: @DanBron it doesn't say "the entire world". It says "everyone". I think the misquote shifts the emphasis towards exaggeration, which is not the point of the original quote. The emphasis of the original quote is on the glass walls, which is a metaphor.

Comment: @GrahamNicol That's exactly the point. The glass walls. Not *everyone*. That's why it's first and foremost a **metaphor for being able to easily see what's going on**.

Comment: @A.P. Everyone means the entire world. I would not turn vegetarian even if I saw how they are slaughtered through glass walls as I have seen *more than a thousand times* on Animal Planet/BBC documentaries how live animals are being eaten by predators. Everyone has a hyperbole element there, too.

Comment: @Rathony I've acknowledged there's an element of exaggeration here multiple times in various comments and my answer. I do not think that's the main driver of the quote, nor do I think this exaggeration qualifies as a hyperbole. The glass wall is the driver, and it's no hyperbole.

Comment: @A.P. There CAN NEVER BE a single slaughter houses in glass walls. They would be prosecuted by the law if they built them. Why isn't it a hyperbole? If all the fishes in the world could walk with 4 legs, no one would eat them. Is it just a metaphor? It's impossible.

Comment: (A) Never say never. The whole point of the documentaries and the campaigns is to change the legislation. (B) It's not a hyperbole because the point of the **glass walls** is not to exaggerate, but to **convey the idea of transparency, truth, knowledge. It is an implicit comparison. Hence, a metaphor.**

Comment: @A.P. BTW, why do you keep referring to transparency, truth and knowledge? Do you think many non-vegetarians are so ignorant that they don't know how those animals are being killed? They just don't want to watch it. And believe me you will be prosecuted if you run a glass-wall slaughter house. No, you won't get necessary approval from the authority to build it in the first place.

Comment: @Rathony (A) I refer to transparency, truth and knowledge because that's the point of the metaphor. Glass is transparent, so you can see the truth through it. And seeing gives you experiential (not theoretical) knowledge, which (according to Paul McCartney) should move a person to becoming a vegetarian. (B) You missed my point about the legislation, but that's irrelevant to the current discussion.

Comment: @A.P. This will be my last comment (Believe me!). You commented "The exaggeration of numbers, duration, weight, or similar has to be the point of the statement" below. Then, if I rephrase "If the number of Slaughter Houses with glass walls changes from 0 to all in the world", then it becomes an "*exaggeration*" according to your own logic. What a pity that Paul didn't think about this. He should focus on writing music and singing.

Comment: @Rathony Your comment is a false inference from what I said. And I'm glad it was your last comment, because I believe I said everything I needed about this matter.

Comment: I think _hyperbole_ fits here. According to google's dictionary, it means : **exaggerated statements or claims not meant to be taken literally.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think he is using a ***[hyperbole](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hyperbole)*** to convey the image of animals being slaughtered in front you, whose repulsive  view would turn you into a vegetarian:

> - A figure of speech in which exaggeration is used for emphasis or effect.
> - Exaggerated statements or claims not meant to be taken literally.

Comment: So what exactly is exaggerated, in your opinion? I obviously agree that everyone is an exaggeration, but is that enough to call the whole thing a hyperbole? I disagree that the emphasis is on everyone. I believe the point of the quote is the glass walls, which is no hyperbole, but a metaphor for being able to see inside a slaughterhouse.

Comment: While the 'glass wall' can be a metaphor of transparency and truth, the whole  sentence refers to a fantasy, an exaggeration (have you ever seen Slaughter  Houses with glass walls? ) to convey a shock, a strong effect on the listener.

Comment: I don't think a mere element of exaggeration makes it a hyperbole. The exaggeration of numbers, duration, weight, or similar has to be *the point of the statement*. Just look at the examples under the link you provided: I waited for eternity, she weigh a ton, etc. In the original quote, the only exaggeration is *everyone*. But the main point is **the glass wall metaphor of transparency.** That's the powerful imagery. That's what drives the point home, and it's a metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for is *metaphor*:

> A figure of speech in which *a word or phrase* that ordinarily designates one thing is used to designate another, thus making an implicit comparison.

(Source: American Heritage Dictionary)

I believe the emphasis in the original quote is not on "everyone becoming a vegetarian", but on the glass walls. **Which is a metaphor and a vivid image for being able to easily see what happens inside a slaughterhouse.**

There *is* an element of  exaggeration here, of course (obviously not everyone would become a vegetarian), but I think it's certainly a stretch to call a hypebole.

The exaggeration of numbers, duration, weight, or similar has to be the clear point of the statement for it to be a hyperbole: I waited *for eternity*, she *weighs a ton*, etc.

In the original quote, the main point is the **glass wall metaphor of transparency**. That's the powerful imagery. That's what drives the point home: **glass walls representing something else -- transparency and truth.**

When we read the quote, it's not the *everyone* that captures our imagination, it's the glass walls.

There's a reason why McCartney's documentary is called "Glass Walls" -- http://freefromharm.org/videos/documentaries/meat-org-the-web-site-the-meat-industry-does-not-want-you-to-see/

Comment: I don’t get the downvotes here so I’ll cancel one of them with my +1. That being said, I really don’t see it as either metaphor OR hyperbole, no more than “If ‘ifs & buts’ were candy & nuts we’d **ALL** have a Merry Christmas” is a metaphor OR hyperbole. Neither the exaggerated **all** in the Christmas one (nut allergy sufferers) nor, as you correctly mention, the exaggerated **everyone** in the OP”s phrase is the point of the phrase. I think they’re both just trying to make points based on false, “if,then” premises, just like:“If meat & dairy were fruit & berry, we’d **all** be vegetarians.”

Answer (score 0):

I would say, hyperbole is a subclass of the answer the OP is seeking. Hyperbolic exaggeration is one way in which a statement might be not really true where the variance from truth is intentional and for the effect of some emphasis. There can be others. Similes and metaphors kind of fall into the category, for instance.

Debating whether that's the best characterization of the example given seems like threadjacking. The original question seems like "is there a more general term for all of these kinds of constructions?"